# AsynchronousServerSocketChannel concurrent accepting

Tags: java, concurrency, aio

In the example of official [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html),seems that we should accept connection one by one.This makes me confused,so I read the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/ch/UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java#UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.implAccept%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.nio.channels.CompletionHandler%29) of **sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl** ,in the line 269 there is a comment **check and set flag to prevent concurrent accepting**,So could someone tell me why should prevent current accepting?
 Is this a OS's limit or there is no need to accept connection currently.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd assume it is to prevent creating multiple socket instances or streams when the conection request is received. So it would cause problems to accept concurently. See how the **NIO** is meant to be handled - there should be only a single [Selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) thread to accept connections, however you may have multiple threads to handle the data..

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating concurrency with asynchronicity. When you accept a connection via async I/O you should immediately schedule another asynchronous `accept()`.